# How can I communicate between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

How can I create threads in C++ and communicate between the main thread and another one?

Some code samples would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a book by Anthony Williams called "C++ Concurrency in Action". It discusses programming with threads in C++ including some examples. Unless you make your question **a lot** more concrete, I'd recommend reading it.

Comment: It depends on the kind of communication you need. Mainly, you could use either shared state (a set of variables accessed using synchronization techniques) or message passing (using pipes, sockets, etc.). What are you planning to use those threads for?

Answer (score 2):

Threads share variables with their scope, that's why mutex locks are so important.

So you can communicate pretty easily just by editing a variable common to both threads:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h> 
main()  {
    pthread_t f2_thread, f1_thread; 
    void *f2(), *f1();
    int i1;
    i1 = 1;
    pthread_create(&f1_thread,NULL,f1,&i1);
    pthread_create(&f2_thread,NULL,f2,&i1);
    pthread_join(f1_thread,NULL);
    pthread_join(f2_thread,NULL);
}
void *f1(int *x){
  std::cout << *x << std::endl;
}
void *f2(int *x){
  sleep(1)
  std::cout << ++(*x) << std::endl;
}
```

This should print out:

```
1
2
```

And the variable i1 has been shared between threads. This is one form of communication, you can share classes structs strings, anything you want.

NOTE: This code will almost definitely cause a thread race. This is an example only, you should always use synchronization and thread safe practices when sharing memory between threads.

Comment: I had the impression that the question was about C++ threads rather than Pthreads...

Comment: @DietmarKühl p_threads can be used in c++ i thought it was just a question about threads.

Comment: C++ defines portable thread creation and thread communication primitives. Pthreads work on some but not all platforms supporting threads.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Ok my apologies, but the concept for portable threads is the same, you can still use common variables.

Comment: Yes, indeed. However, not the way you are using them! You **cannot** communicate using variables, not even any built-in type, **without** synchronization! What you have created is a nice, simple example of a data race.

Comment: @DietmarKühl That is why i have mentioned the mutex lock at the start of the answer. The OP simply wanted an example of communication between threads which i believe i have provided.

Comment: i am afraid to have to downvote this, but i sense data races and using nonportable code.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb 1. I have suggested mutex, this code is just a very simple example to show how an integer can be used in two threads. 2. The OP didn't ask for portability or some specific code to do something, he asked for an example of how to communicate between threads. I have provided a simple example of how to do that in one case. At no point did I state it was portable or useful, it is simply an example.

Comment: While i agree this is not portable, this does indeed show what the OP was asking by showing 2 threads using a common variable is some form of communication, though this is not true communication this is just 2 threads changing the same variable, for true communication between threads they should be using IPC, also if they are going to just use variables aka shared memory they should not be on the stack but allocated on the heap since in c++ the heap is shared memory, also should use some form of message passing which falls along the lines of IPC (Inter-process Communication)

Answer (score 1):

In thread creation the answer is obvious( I think it is ), either `std::thread` if you have C++11 or `boost::thread` otherwise, but in case of message passing it depend on your problem and your programming style.
 As a general purpose solution I prefer the use of `boost::asio::io_service` it is very flexible and you can post any kind of function or function object to be executed in context of other thread, using this technique you don't need any mutex or such and also you can group threads to consumers and producers and many other useful features are available.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i will tell you simplest of i know: `_beginthread`

- You must incude `process.h` for this to work.
- There must be a function to be threaded.
- Functions parameter inlet must be (void *).
- Function should have a `_endthread()`  when it is needed to be ended.

In the below program, two threads compete against finding the pi value.
If one of them finds the value pi, it informs the other thread that it should end. Also in the main() it is printed which one found the pi. Third thread just waits one of other threads to finish.

```
      #include<process.h>
      #include<windows.h> //for the Sleep()
      #include<stdio.h>
      volatile boolean found=false;
      volatile int who=0;

      void find_pi_core1(void * iterations)
      {

          int * ite=(int *)iterations;
          for(int i=0;i<ite;i++)
          {
              //a sample of Monte-Carlo method here to find pi 
              //gets pi with more precision with additional iterations
               if(found) _endthread();
          }
          found=true;who=1;
          _endthread();    

       }

       void find_pi_core2(void * iterations)
       {

           int * ite=(int *)iterations;
           for(int i=0;i<ite;i++)
           {
                //a sample of Monte-Carlo method here to find pi 
                //gets pi with more precision with additional iterations
                 if(found) _endthread();
           }
           found=true;who=2;
          _endthread();
      }

       void printscreeN(void * dummy)
       {

          while(!found)
          {
              Sleep(30);      //if dont sleep, it gets a lot of cpu power
          }
          printf(" found! \n" );
          _endthread();
      }

      int main()
      {

                      Function name
                          ^       Stack size
                          |          ^           Function parameter
                          |          |             ^
          _beginthread(find_pi_core1,0,(void *) 3000000);
          _beginthread(find_pi_core2,0,(void *) 2500000);
          _beginthread(printscreeN,0,(void *)0);
          Sleep(3000);
          if(found)
          { 
               printf("pi has been found! core-%d has found pi first ",who);
          }
          else
          {printf("pi has not been bound!");}
          return 0;
      }
```

Answer (score -2):

Thread creation is OS dependent.

on Linux, you may use the pthread library function pthread_create to create threads, and use pthread_join to wait for the thread to finish.

On Windows, you may use the CreateThread() Windows API function to create threads, and use the WaitForSingleObject() function to wait for the thread to finish.

Comment: Or you use `std::thread` or `boost::thread` on both.

Comment: The current C++ standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2011) defines thread creation and thread communication primitives, i.e., it isn't OS dependent at all.